# Update RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Here my custom RecyclerView.Adapter

```
public abstract class MyCustomRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<?> data = new ArrayList<>();

    public DataBindingRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<?> data) {

        this.context = context;
        if (data != null) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

     public void updateData(List data) {
         this.data.clear();
        if (data != null) {
            this.data.addAll(data);
        }
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

As you can see it has method `updateData()`. This method refresh adapter.
If use only method `notifyDataSetChanged` it's not refresh adapter. I need clean all items then use `addAll()` and in the end call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Only in this sequence it's work - refresh adapter.

The question is: Maybe has another (more simple) solution to refresh adapter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simplify your full refresh method if null is allowed as data source:

```
public void updateData(List data) {
    this.data = data;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

There is also class in support library for handling `RecyclerView` model update: [**DiffUtil**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html)

If you need to handle move/add/remove in more elegant way, that is definitely worth looking.

Answer (score 0):

put your `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the activity or fragment and call it from the adapter